# How to use UIPopOver to input text in to UITextField?

Tags: objective-c, delegates, uitextfield, uipopovercontroller

I would like to learn how would I make a UITextField get text from a UIPopover view. Let's say I have buttons with numbers on my popover and I want these numbers to be input into the textfield.

Some people sugested to us BOOL like this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *) textField {
  [self.myPopover presentPopoverFromRect:textField.frame 
        inView:self.view 
        permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
        animated:YES];
  return NO;
}
```

And one more:

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
  if(popoverController == nil){   //make sure popover isn't displayed more than once in the view
    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverDetailContent]; 
  }
  [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:textView.frame 
        inView:self.view 
        permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
        animated:YES];
  popoverController.delegate = self;
  return NO; // tells the textfield not to start its own editing process (ie show the keyboard)
}
```

Both are not making much change, my textField still calls the default iPad keyboard instead of my popover.
Second example uses delegate popoverController and my controller is `flipsidePopoverController`.

Could I use an IBAction like this?

```
- (IBAction)togglePopover:(id)sender {
  if (self.flipsidePopoverController) {
    [self.flipsidePopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    self.flipsidePopoverController = nil;
  } else {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showAlternate" sender:sender];
  }
}
```

Comment: Gosh it must be very difficult question